# Access currently active displayed UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I want to present a ModalView, everytime my application receives a Pushnotification.
On arrival of the Notification, my app displays any of the `UIViewController`s within the app.

I need this `UIViewController` to call

```
[presentingViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
// presentingViewController is what I need :)
```

**Is there a way to find out which UIViewController is currently active?**

I would know how to do this with e.g. `UITabbarController` or `UINavigationController`, but I can't rely on the presence of either of these.

I also tried getting the rootViewController via

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]
```

and presenting the ModalView from there, but - of course - it wouldn't show for any other pushed/displayed views.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to get a global variable of type id or UIViewController that you update every time you display a controller . This way you will always have a reference to the current controller.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: The problem with this approach would be touching other code outside my class, which is not possible.